# How do you set the DateTime format string in Newtonsoft?

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm trying to get Newtonsoft to convert a string to a DateTime. This is the string:

```
13/02/2019 05:13
```

I **try** to tell Newtonsoft how to do this by using one of these:

```
var dateTimeConverter = new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" };
var converters = new List<JsonConverter>() { dateTimeConverter };
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = converters
};
```

or

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    DateFormatString = "dd'/'MM'/'yyyy' 'HH':'mm"
};
```

and of course it will just go right ahead and tell me that's fine and then blow up as it tries to process the second day of the thirteenth month.

I need this to work globally. How do I get Newtonsoft to do this?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem - see https://gist.github.com/jskeet/3fa65c63fcc4a8235c8d3d5a5b985f46. Please could you provide a [mcve] that shows it failing? (My guess is that whatever's doing the parsing isn't using the default settings, but we don't know anything about your context.)

Comment: @JonSkeet hmm, you are right. wtf. Okay upon further inspection it appears to NEVER use my format string even though if I check it later on (say in a controller) it has the value that I set. Also, did you downvote my question?

Comment: No, I didn't, although the lack of context does make it currently a less-than-useful question IMO. (There's no way that anyone could provide the answer that you have from the question itself.)

Comment: Well hindsight is 20/20. It's a lot of effort to distill an entire problem into something digestable in stackoverflow format. Up until I found the problem was with WebAPI I assumed I was using Newtonsoft wrong. Plus I didn't know where the problem was. It's kind of unreasonable to ask someone who is asking a question to provide you with all the relevent details you need to answer that question, right? Like, how do they know. Also, thanks for answering that question.

Comment: The thing to do is try to reproduce the problem in a minimal way before you ask a question, and include that [mcve] in the question itself. That helps find contextual issues beforehand, and will often help you to find the problem yourself. I don't think it's unreasonable to ask that users provide enough information for us to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This was in WebAPI and the problem was I wasn't setting the same Json.Net that WebAPI was using.

I fixed it by putting this in Application_Start of **global.asax.cs**:

```
var dateTimeConverter = new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" };
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(dateTimeConverter);
```

Answer (score -1):

you can convert a string to a datetime like this :

```
string iString = "2005-05-05 22:12 PM";
DateTime oDate = DateTime.ParseExact(iString, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm tt",null);
MessageBox.Show(oDate.ToString());
```

i hope to help you.. :/

Comment: This does not answer the question of how to get JSON.NET to do this as part of deserialization. Getting the data raw and then converting it afterwards is always an option, but that's not exactly convenient.

Comment: IList<DateTime> dateList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<DateTime>>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    DateFormatString = "d MMMM, yyyy"
});

like this ?